# Creating event in PyQGIS that notices that group of layers is selected

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, events, group-layer, interface

I have these groups of layers with their layers inside in QGIS:

[image: Layers with groups of layers]

I have an event in PyQGIS that notices when I select a layer like RODAL or MONTE:

```py
iface.layerTreeView().currentLayerChanged.connect(self.eventoClickPanelCapas)
```

However, what I really want is to have an event that notices when I select a group of layers, for example, PT_P000052SA_N. I don't know if it is possible or not.

Comment: You can use `iface.layerTree().selectionModel().selectionChanged` signal. See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/449736/how-to-see-the-number-of-layers-currently-selected-in-qgis/449750) for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use and modify this script:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsLayerTreeNode

view = iface.layerTreeView()

def eventoClickPanelCapas():
    selected = view.selectedNodes()
    if len(selected)==1 and selected[0].nodeType()==QgsLayerTreeNode.NodeGroup:
        print("Group selected")
    
view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(eventoClickPanelCapas)
```

[image]